# tomcat : export static content from filesystem folders with Active Directory authentication (and without writing Java .wars)

Tags: file, authentication, tomcat, static

I learned something about JDNI Realms binding to Active Directory, but when it comes to exporting filesystem folders with static files using this authentication, every example involves some web.xml which as I understand has different XML schema, and should be located somewhere within .war file to be deployed.
What I am trying to achieve, is the simplest deployable file set which would create a Tomcat context with AD/JNDI realm and a description of exported (read only) folders accessible with authentication through this realm. Is there a way I could achieve this goal without resorting to writing some Java application (which is not my specialization), and using only built-in functionality provided by Tomcat ?
Thank you in advance for your responses

Comment: All content served by Tomcat **must** come from web applications (either WAR files or unzipped WAR files, i.e. folders): without any web applications Tomcat can only serve errors. However, since Servlet 3.0, the minimal web application is an empty WAR file (or empty folder).

Comment: So you **need** to create a web applications (let's say `webapps/app`), create a `WEB-INF/web.xml` file inside as the one you mention, configure an authentication realm in `server.xml` and a security constraint in `web.xml`.